# What does Not if mean here?

Tags: meaning

I was watching the new movie of Jim Carrey named *Dumb and Dumber 2* when I heard some dialogue which I didn't understand. In the following text, what is the meaning of B?

> A: "Well, nice catching up."
>
> B: "Not if I see you first."

Comment: According to https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2096672/characters/nm0001099, the joke is in its usual form: - "[...] Well, nice catching up. **See you later.**" - "**Not If I see you first!**".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I can't say I've seen that movie, but I'm assuming it's a joke.

It's not uncommon to say "see you later," to which someone might respond "not if I see you first" as a joke. This dialogue takes it a step further, showing that character B doesn't even understand the meaning of the joke, so he uses it severely out of context.

No, pertinently, this doesn't make any direct sense in English.

Comment: Actually, these were the last conversation between them. the character B didn't like the way the A behaved and got sad at him.B said that sentence in an angry way. I would like to learn the meaning of not if and in order to use it. thank you

Comment: @English Don't use it. It is on its face very insulting to tell some you will actively avoid meeting them again; it's something you can only say to close friends, and only if they already understand that it's a joke.

Answer (score 1):

A. Means nice reconnecting after not seeing someone for some time.

B. Is probably in the context of a joke.  Like person one says "See you later" as a phrase for goodbye.  The responder uses the "see" literally, saying "Not if I *see* you first".

Answer (score 0):

"**If** I see you first, I'll do my best to avoid you, so you don't see me and we do **not** have the opportunity for a so-called nice catching up."